# how to develop my project from 2 different computers using github

Tags: git, github

I want to have the possibility to develop my laravel project from 2 different computers.
But it seems I do something wrong.

I created a project on PC1.
Install git for windows.
Then go to the project folder and initialize the project.

```
git init
```

Then add files and folders I want to be synchronized with Github

```
git add README.md  composer.json app resources tests artisan config package.json routes bootstrap database phpunit.xml server.php webpack.mix.js
```

Do first commit

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Create a link with the empty repository on GitHub

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/my/repo.git
```

Upload local files to Github

```
git push -f origin master
```

WIthout f git returns an error. I don't know how to solve, but as far as I know, GitHub repo is empty and I have nothing to lost I just use force and it is OK.

The first step is done.
I have a project on PC1 synchronized with GitHub.

Now I want to clone this project on PC2

I create a fresh laravel project.

```
laravel new blog
```

Clone my project files from GitHub to temporary folder and then move them to the blog folder.

```
git clone https://github.com/my/repo.git
```

Go to the project folder and initialize the project.

```
git init
```

Create a link with GitHub repository

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/my/repo.git
```

Add files and folders I want to be synchronized with GitHub

```
git add README.md  composer.json app resources tests artisan config package.json routes bootstrap database phpunit.xml server.php webpack.mix.js
```

Then if I do git status I see that all files, which I cloned from GitHub are marked for commit
So I am a little bit confused about what to do.

```
git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   README.md
        new file:   app/Admin/Controllers/AuthController.php
        new file:   app/Admin/Controllers/ExampleController.php
        new file:   app/Admin/Controllers/FurnituraController.php
        new file:   app/Admin/Controllers/HomeController.php
        new file:   app/Admin/Controllers/NewsController.php
        ....
```

Comment: you're doing the part where setting up PC2 is completely wrong. Follow this guide 
http://www.deanbodenham.com/learn/using-git-to-sync-different-computers.html

Comment: all you should do in PC2 phase is git clone. that's it, you're ready to work.

Answer (score 2):

You should not `git init` and add your existing repository as remote.
The `git clone` should be enough.

And you could add all the files, minus the [`.gitignore` for laravel project](http://gitignore.io/api/laravel), instead of a subset.
See then "[Connecting the Laravel Project on GitHub.](https://medium.com/@ujalajha/connecting-the-laravel-project-on-github-73acf55bbd63)" from **[Ujala Jha](https://github.com/ujalajha)**.

Comment: I tested few time more and really for PC2 `git clone` is enough. But I cannot understand why after first push from PC1 to fresh repo on github (contains only readme.md) I got error and can onlu do this push using F key

Comment: git push -u origin master

Comment: ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)

Comment: error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/my/repo.git'

Comment: hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do

Comment: hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing

Comment: hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes

Comment: hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Comment: That was small help, which I see under error, but even if I do `git pull origin master` doesn't solve the issue. Only `git push -f origin master` do the job, but after that  readme.md disappears from github.

Comment: First push on GitHub, if the repo (GitHub) is not empty, would mean forcing the push. Or pulling first.